# Data Extraction using HTML DOM

Tags: php, html

I am having an issue regarding data extraction, I have also seen a lot of topic regarding this issue but I am not able to find any solution that meet my requirements so I request you to please help me in this error.

```
<?php 
    require('admin/inc/simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = file_get_contents("http://health.hamariweb.com/rawalpindi/doctors");

    $title = $html->find("div#infinite-grid-images", 0)->innertext;

    echo $title;

?>
```

I want to show all these doctors to my website I am just learning data extraction and I have seen a lot of tutorials but still no result, please anyone who can help me :(

Comment: `file_get_contents` returns a string, not an object. You could start with http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php.

Comment: if I understand you correctly. Are you trying to extract data from an external site?

Comment: yeah, exactly i want to extract data from external site and i tried file_get_html as well but no result, can you please write a piece of code so that i can understand what i have to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading the string returned by file_get_content().

```
<?php 
    require('admin/inc/simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_contents("http://health.hamariweb.com/rawalpindi/doctors");
    $dom = new simple_html_dom();
    $dom->load($html);
    $title = $dom->find("#infinite-grid-images", 0)->innertext;

    echo $title;

?>
```

Also, shipped within the `simple_html_dom.php` file is a function called:
    `file_get_html($url)`

You can do something like:

```
<?php 
    require('admin/inc/simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html("http://health.hamariweb.com/rawalpindi/doctors");
    if($html){
        $title = $dom->find("#infinite-grid-images", 0)->innertext;

        echo $title;
    }else{
        echo "Nothing found";
    }
?>
```

Good luck!

Also curl is your friend.

```
<?php
    require('simple_html_dom.php');
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://health.hamariweb.com/rawalpindi/doctors",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
    ));
    $file = curl_exec($curl);
    $error = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $dom = new simple_html_dom();
    $dom->load($file);
    $doctorDivs = $dom->find("#infinite-grid-images", 0)->children();
    $doctors = array();
    foreach($doctorDivs as $div){
        $doctor = array();
        $doctor["image"] = "http://health.hamariweb.com/".$div->find('img', 0)->src;
        $details = $div->find('table', 1)->find("tr");
        $doctor["name"] = trim($details[0]->plaintext);
        $doctor["type"] = trim($details[1]->plaintext);
        $doctor["etc"] = trim($details[2]->plaintext);
        $doctors[] = $doctor;
    }
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($doctors);
?>
```

You can decide what to do with the data.

Comment: It is not working, when i run the it shows:

Warning: file_get_contents(http://health.hamariweb.com/rawalpindi/doctors): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in C:\xampp\htdocs\DExplorer\admin\inc\simple_html_dom.php on line 32
Nothing found

Comment: As Pedro Lobito said you need to provide a  User-agent

Comment: it works for me :) but i have a little question is it possible that i can extract data of doctor from that webpage according to his specialization i mean there are a lot of doctors are mentioned over there some are dentist and some are neurologist. so my question is that is it possible to extract data of doctor with the category of dentist.

one more thing, how can i get the picture of doctors.

Comment: I have edited my answer. In the same spirit you can _crawl_ the rest of the page. Read the [docs](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) and good luck.

Comment: It is absolutely perfect and your code is quite easy to understand thank you for making it too easy for and is it possible that i can insert extracted data to my database.

Comment: my database table structure is :
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT into doctors(id, name, spec, qualification) VALUES('','','','')");

Answer (score 0):

The website you're trying to scrap, returns a [http 500 error](https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938) if **no user agent is used**, to bypass that, you can use [curl](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), i.e.:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://health.hamariweb.com/rawalpindi/doctors");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0");
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
# your code ...
```

Comment: Can you please guide me that how can i extract data from external websites dynamically. I mean,

if someone use search bar on my website and enter the keyword "Best dentist in rawalpindi".
If there is no data that match the above mentioned keyword in my database than i want my web to search that result on google.
I want my web to dynamically extract data from top 3 google search results.
Is it possible, If Yes then please guide me how can i do this.